# how to develop web service which runs background job

Tags: web-services, perl

Assuming we have a program a which calls a service b on another machine (both developed by me).

The service on the machine b could take hours, so holding a http connection for so long is impossible.

I need somehow that process b will notify process a that it finished and return the results.

Which technology may i use to solve this problem?

I thought about the following solution:

- Process b will return a process id to process a
- Process a will ask every x minutes if the process finished
- If it finished, it will return the results

Is there an "Off-the-shelf" solution / module for this

Comment: Your idea sounds viable. I've consumed stuff like this in mayor ecom platforms. You start a large job and ask about the status. But there is no way `b` can tell `a` about the status of its own accord. `a` has to ask. Imagine you have a wheelbarrow of some stuff you need to get done. You carry it over to the worker, dump it on their desk and every couple of minutes you shout through the office "are you done yet?!". At some point they'll say they're done and you can ask about the result. Don't forget to thank them though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are job managers desinged for this, for example [gearman](http://gearman.org/) (and others). You could also implement it with a message queue like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (and others) or [Redis](http://redis.io/).

If you want something that's easy to set up, I would go with Redis, although it's not the same as a job manager and might require more programming.